# MySQL Group By and Indeterminate Results

Tags: mysql

I've been researching about using MySQL Group By and Joins correctly to avoid Indeterminate values for non-aggregated values in other columns. Now, with my below query, how could I ensure the correct Vin Number is selected with the minimum test drive time when I'm grouping by the customer ID? Basically, how can I ensure I get the entire row associated with the minimum test drive time?

```
  SELECT t1.ID AS CUSTOMERID, t1.carhash, 
             MIN(t1.testdrivetime) AS testdrivetime,
               t2.vinnumber AS vinnumber

               FROM TABLE1 t1

        INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t2.vinnumber = t1.carhash

INNER JOIN (SELECT t1.ID, MIN(testdrivetime) AS testdrivetime
        FROM TABLE1
        GROUP BY t1.ID) f
    ON f.ID = t1.ID AND f.testdrivetime = t1.testdrivetime

GROUP BY ID
```

#### Times in database:

```
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------------|
|          ID         |      carhash     |       testdrivetime     |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------------|
|          12         |         345      |           2:22          |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------------|
|          12         |         277      |           4:51          |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------------|
```

#### Output with above query (Wrong car hash since it's indeterminant):

```
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------------|
|          ID         |      carhash     |       testdrivetime     |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------------|
|          12         |         277      |           2:22          |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------------|
```

#### Output I want: (with correct carhash from same row as minimum test drive time)

```
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------------|
|          ID         |      carhash     |       testdrivetime     |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------------|
|          12         |         345      |           2:22          |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------------|
```

Comment: You got it, just a moment

Comment: Edited my original post, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

- In a sub-select query ([Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)), determine the minimum `testdrivetime` value for each `ID`.
- Join this result-set back to the main table using `ID` and `testdrivetime`, to get the row corresponding to minimum `testdrivetime` value.

Try:

```
SELECT 
  t.* 
FROM your_table AS t 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    ID, 
    MIN(testdrivetime) AS min_testdrivetime 
  FROM your_table 
  GROUP BY ID
) AS dt 
  ON dt.ID = t.ID AND 
     dt.min_testdrivetime = t.testdrivetime
```

Comment: oh, so I wouldn't need to do anything else with t2.vinnumber to get the correct row with that as well?

Comment: @duke no. give it a try. From your question, it is unclear that what is the usage of `vinnumber`

Comment: For the t2.vinnumber, I have to Join two tables together with t1.carhash and t2.vinnumber to get the correct number for the car. Even though I got the minimum test drive time, the vin number value is indeterminant since I haven't specified what row to get it from. It isn't a Min or Max vin number either since the numbers will range.